# error while creating stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm getting following error while creating stored procedure in mysql like as follows

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

Bellow one is my stored procedure

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> create procedure music_procedure(in movie_name varchar(100),in movie_image varchar(100),in music_director varchar(150),in cast varchar(150),in songtitle varchar(150),in duration time,in artist varchar(100),in lyricist varchar(100),in status varchar(50))

-> begin

->  if not exists (select movie_name from music where music.movie_name=movie_name) then

-> insert into music(movie_name,movie_image,music_director,cast) values(movie_name,movie_image,music_director,cast);

-> insert into music_details(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,music_id) values(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,(select music_id from music where music.movie_name=movie_name));

 -> else

-> insert into music_details(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,music_id) values(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,(select music_id from music where music.movie_name=movie_name));


-> end


-> //
```

Comment: I don't see an `end if`

Answer (score 1):

add `end if;` in the your code

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> create procedure music_procedure(in movie_name varchar(100),in movie_image varchar(100),in music_director varchar(150),in cast varchar(150),in songtitle varchar(150),in duration time,in artist varchar(100),in lyricist varchar(100),in status varchar(50))

-> begin

->  if not exists (select movie_name from music where music.movie_name=movie_name) then

-> insert into music(movie_name,movie_image,music_director,cast) values(movie_name,movie_image,music_director,cast);

-> insert into music_details(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,music_id) values(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,(select music_id from music where music.movie_name=movie_name));

 -> else

-> insert into music_details(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,music_id) values(songtitle,duration,artist,lyricist,status,(select music_id from music where music.movie_name=movie_name));


-> end if;


-> //
```

Comment: You also need the `end` to match `begin`.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing `END IF;`. Put it just before your `END` statement;

Comment: That shouldn't matter, whitespace is inignificant.